# How do I wait for something to finish in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Downloading...";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string program = "Program";
            string link = "https://linkhere.com";
            string download = wc.DownloadString(link);
            string path = "Program\\" + program + ".zip";
            string patch = "Program";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(patch);
            wc.DownloadFile(download, path);
            label1.Text = "Downloaded!";
        }
```

I want to make the label1.Text = "Downloaded!"; to happen after it downloads the program.

Comment: _"I want to make the label1.Text = "Downloaded!"; to happen after it downloads the program."_ - thats exactly what should happen as you've chosen the synchronous version of that download method.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit you post and try to be more precise on the problem: what is the exact difference between the expected and actual outcome of your code. Up to now we don't really see the problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the download asynchronous to prevent the deadlock.

```
private async void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Downloading...";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string program = "Program";
    string link = "https://linkhere.com";
    string download = wc.DownloadString(link);
    string path = "Program\\" + program + ".zip";
    string patch = "Program";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(patch);
    await wc.DownloadFileAsync(download, path);
    label1.Text = "Downloaded!";
}
```

Comment: `DownloadFileAsync` != `DownloadFileTaskAsync` (it's not awaitable) -- WebClient really needs to be disposed of.

Comment: @Jimi it's pretty standard practice to have an instance of WebClient running for the lifetime of the class. What version of .net are you on?

Comment: That's a local object. -- The .Net version is not factor.

Comment: The most important thing is that `DownloadFileAsync` is not awaitable, it's event-driven.

Comment: @Jimi you're doing something wrong, it is awaitable

Comment: `public void DownloadFileAsync (Uri address, string fileName);` -- declared `void`: how do you await `void`? Doesn't matter, it's not awaitable, as mentioned it's event-driven. The awaitable method is the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` counterpart (which of course returns a `Task`).

Comment: @dr.null It's not about awaiting an async call in an `async void` method, it's DownloadFileAsync that is not awaitable. It's an [AsyncOperation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/AsyncOperation.cs,e6f378e28a257e11), i.e., it's *asynchronous* in the *old* terms, driven by events, it cannot be handled as a Task, simply because it's not.

Comment: @Jimi aha, got it. Thank you Jim.

Answer (score 0):

The [DownloadFile docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile) say "This method blocks while downloading the resource", so I'm not sure what could be different about your situation, or if there even is a problem.

I suspect that you never see `"Downloading..."` because the UI does not update in between the two `label1.Text` update calls. Adding **[`Application.DoEvents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents)** after the first `.Text` update may help.

Comment: As for the `Application.DoEvents`, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/14171304).

Answer (score 0):

Please Use tasks and events to handle the situation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your download to with this as reference.

```
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Task task1 = new Task(() => ActionToWork1());
        Task task2 = new Task(() => ActionToWork2());
        
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        Console.WriteLine("All task done.");    
    }
    
    private static void ActionToWork1(){
        Console.WriteLine("Working on Task 1"); 
    }
    
    private static void ActionToWork2(){
        Console.WriteLine("Working on Task 2"); 
    }
```